# Using any font with firacode ligatures vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

I saw image on one dark pro github repo. however this is not firacode although it uses it's font ligatures. how can I do it? [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Ligaturizer](https://github.com/ToxicFrog/Ligaturizer) on GitHub. This project allows you to add font ligatures to any coding font by running a Python script.

They also included pre-ligaturized fonts in the [release page here](https://github.com/ToxicFrog/Ligaturizer/releases/tag/v4) (Download `LigaturizedFonts.zip`) so that you can directly install those fonts without the need of running the script by yourself.

Comment: I tried the Hack version of that. btw do you know the font in that image

Comment: Sorry I don't know the font from the image. [This website](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) may help you find out

Comment: @Anupama Does this answer your question?